# php String Concatenation doesn't work

Tags: php, syntax, concatenation

Hey guys I can't seem to understand it, how would it be to write this correctly:

```
$htmlEchoVariable = "<div class='content1'>
                            <div id='img_content1'>
                            <img src='".$row['Picture0']."' alt=""/>
                        </div>";
```

How to enter the `$row['Picture0']` correctly? It gives me errors an I cant understand what to do.

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: php designer says "unexpected "" "

Comment: why the `/` at end of first div? those are for unclosed tags, like `<br />` and are not even necessary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is in the `alt=""` part. Change the double quotes to single quotes, like so:

```
$htmlEchoVariable = "<div class='content1'>
                        <div id='img_content1'>
                        <img src='".$row['Picture0']."' alt='' />
                    </div>";
```

Or you can add some slashes before the double quotes so they are treated as a part of the string:

```
alt=\"\"
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot:

```
$htmlEchoVariable = "<div class='content1'>
                        <div id='img_content1'>
                        <img src='{$row['Picture0']}' alt=""/>
                    </div>";
```

Comment: @Martti read about those braces. they have various uses. but it still should not work because of the `alt=""`

Comment: I said nothing about the braces. I asked him to read my answer, which has the solution to the *original* problem, which you also happen to point out.